# Change ajax select2 value using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select field:

```
<select class="form-control" name="nacionalidade_id" id="nacionalidade_id">
</select>
```

This receive the data from ajax:

```
$('#nacionalidade_id').select2({
    placeholder: 'Selecione o país de nascimento',
    ajax: {
        url: 'assets/dados/nacionalidade.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function(data){
            return{
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

The nacionalidade.php:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM nacionalidades where descricao like '%" . $_GET['q'] . "%' limit 20");

$json = [];

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while ($nacionalidade = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $json[] = ['id'=>$nacionalidade['id'], 'text'=>$nacionalidade['descricao']];
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

I want to select the option when `id = 45` using jquery.

I try:

```
function buscaCidadao(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/funcoesPhp/buscaCidadao.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {'cns': $('#cns').val()},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#nacionalidade_id").val(45).change();
        },
    });
}
```

But it's not work. Any idea?

Exists this code: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2 but I can't adapt for my code. Any help.

Comment: try $("#nacionalidade_id").val(45).change();

Comment: @LahiruTM not work

Comment: How do you set it. Because i am using this method when i want to edit already saved row by clicking Edit button to set saved data in to the edit form before save it, it is working perfectly.

Comment: as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wf1aje8k/2/) it works

Comment: @LahiruTM I edit my post to you see

Comment: check your select2 and jquery versions. Also check your browser's javascript console for errors and warnings. Otherwise your code is ok.

Comment: @LahiruTM select2 4.0.6 / jquery 3.3.1.min / no errors or warnings on console

Comment: I found this link https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2 but I can't adapt to my code. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#nacionalidade_id').val('45'); 
$('#nacionalidade_id').trigger('change');
```

See select2 docs at https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options

Comment: Not work, reading the link I found this https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2 but I can't create the code

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a new otpion:

```
var data = {
    id: 45,
    text: 'TEXT DESCRIPTION'
};
var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
$('#nacionalidade_id').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```